# The Region $0<y<\pi$ under the mapping $w=e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I have a region in the complex plane, defined simply as
$$0<y<\pi$$
This is just an infinite horizontal strip from $0$ to $\pi$ on the $z$-plane.  Considering the complex map then $w=e^z$, I am trying to see how this map affects the given region.  Starting with $z=x+iy, w=u+iv$, I know that
$$w=e^z=e^xe^{iy}=e^x\cos{y}+ie^x\sin{y}=u+iv$$
Thus $u=e^x\cos{y}, v=e^x\sin{y}$.  Since $e^x>0$ for all real $x$, i focus on the trigonometric components of $u$ and $v$.  Since $\cos{y}\gt 0$ for all $0<y<\pi$, then $u\gt 0$.  So the map is at least in the right half of the $w$-plane.  It's here that I start to get lost, so I switch to polar:
$$w=e^z=e^xe^{iy}=\rho e^{iy}$$
Therefore, $\rho=e^x$, and $\theta=y$.  Therefore, since $\rho$ can take all values except, $0$, we have our horizontal strip mapped to the upper half of the $w$-plane with a singular point at $w=0$. Is the upper plane, since $ 0<y=\theta<\pi$.

Thus, my final intuition is that this horizontal strip is mapped to the upper $w$-plane where $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v>0$.  Is this right or am I off?

Comment: It's indeed the upper half-plane. You wrote that $\cos y > 0$ for all $0 < y < \pi$, but you got that mixed up, $\cos y < 0$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} < y < \frac{3\pi}{2}$. It's $\sin y > 0$ for $0 < y < \pi$.

Comment: It's always the small mistakes that lead to confusion, i always say...I mixed up my sin and cos.  In general, when considering the map $w=e^z$, is it easier to consider polar form than cartesian?  It seems like a better approach since $y=\theta$ if you consider as i showed above.

Comment: For $e^z$, when considering the image, it's good to use polar form, and for the domain, Cartesian. For $e^z$ maps the lines $\operatorname{Re} z = c$ to circles centred at $0$, and the lines $\operatorname{Im} z = c$ to rays emanating from $0$.